# how to list all the epoll requests in linux

Tags: linux, socket

I used to use netstat for displaying all listening sockets. How can we list epoll requests on the sockets? Or is there anyway to dislay epoll requests using netstat?

Comment: have a look at sysdig and dtrace4linux